# Derivative of a function one of arguments of which is a constant

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I'm trying to differentiate the function $h(t)=t+hf(c,t+hf(c,t))$ (only $t$ is a variable). I'm kind of confused by the fact that it looks like $f$ has two arguments, even though one of them is constant. Should I just ignore the first argument? If so, would the result be this:

$$h'(t)=1+hf_t(c,t+hf(c,t))\cdot (1+hf_t(c,t))?$$

Comment: Do you know to differentiate two variable functions?

Comment: Use the chain rule for partial derivatives.  And whenever you get $dc/dt$ you know it is $0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$ c $ is a constant.

put
$$f(c,y)=F(y)$$
So,
$$F'(y)=\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(c,y)$$
and
$$h(t)=t+hF(t+hF(t))$$
thus
$$h'(t)=1+hF'(t+hF(t))(1+hF'(t))$$

$$=1+h\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(c,t+hf(c,t))\Bigl(1+h\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(c,t)\Bigr)$$